# Pitch Shifting on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to change pitch of some recorded sound using PitchShifter.java class below:

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.util.MathUtilities;

//package com.course.android.voicechanger;

//import android.util.Log;

/****************************************************************************
 *
 * NAME: PitchShift.cs
 * VERSION: 1.2
 * HOME URL: http://www.dspdimension.com
 * KNOWN BUGS: none
 *
 * SYNOPSIS: Routine for doing pitch shifting while maintaining
 * duration using the Short Time Fourier Transform.
 *
 * DESCRIPTION: The routine takes a pitchShift factor value which is between 0.5
 * (one octave down) and 2. (one octave up). A value of exactly 1 does not change
 * the pitch. numSampsToProcess tells the routine how many samples in indata[0...
 * numSampsToProcess-1] should be pitch shifted and moved to outdata[0 ...
 * numSampsToProcess-1]. The two buffers can be identical (ie. it can process the
 * data in-place). fftFrameSize defines the FFT frame size used for the
 * processing. Typical values are 1024, 2048 and 4096. It may be any value <=
 * MAX_FRAME_LENGTH but it MUST be a power of 2. osamp is the STFT
 * oversampling factor which also determines the overlap between adjacent STFT
 * frames. It should at least be 4 for moderate scaling ratios. A value of 32 is
 * recommended for best quality. sampleRate takes the sample rate for the signal 
 * in unit Hz, ie. 44100 for 44.1 kHz audio. The data passed to the routine in 
 * indata[] should be in the range [-1.0, 1.0), which is also the output range 
 * for the data, make sure you scale the data accordingly (for 16bit signed integers
 * you would have to divide (and multiply) by 32768). 
 *
 * COPYRIGHT 1999-2006 Stephan M. Bernsee <smb [AT] dspdimension [DOT] com>
 *
 *                                              The Wide Open License (WOL)
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, distribute and sell this software and its
 * documentation for any purpose is hereby granted without fee, provided that
 * the above copyright notice and this license appear in all source copies. 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
 * ANY KIND. See www.dspguru.com/wol.htm for more information.
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************
 * 
 * This code was converted to C# by Michael Knight madmik3 at gmail dot com. sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/
 * 
 *****************************************************************************/

public class PitchShifter2 {

    private static int MAX_FRAME_LENGTH = 16000;
    private static float[] gInFIFO = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gOutFIFO = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gFFTworksp = new float[2 * MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gLastPhase = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH / 2 + 1];
    private static float[] gSumPhase = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH / 2 + 1];
    private static float[] gOutputAccum = new float[2 * MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gAnaFreq = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gAnaMagn = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gSynFreq = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static float[] gSynMagn = new float[MAX_FRAME_LENGTH];
    private static long gRover, gInit;

    public static void PitchShift2(float pitchShift, long numSampsToProcess, float sampleRate, float[] indata) {
        // PitchShift2(pitchShift, numSampsToProcess, (long) 256, (long) 10, sampleRate, indata);

        PitchShift2(pitchShift, numSampsToProcess, (long) 1024, (long) 32, sampleRate, indata);
    }

    public static void PitchShift2(float pitchShift, long numSampsToProcess, long fftFrameSize, long osamp, float sampleRate, float[] indata) {

        double magn, phase, tmp, window, real, imag;
        double freqPerBin, expct;
        long i, k, qpd, index, inFifoLatency, stepSize, fftFrameSize2;

        float[] outdata = indata;
        /* set up some handy variables */
        fftFrameSize2 = fftFrameSize / 2;
        stepSize = fftFrameSize / osamp;
        freqPerBin = sampleRate / (double) fftFrameSize;
        expct = 2.0 * Math.PI * (double) stepSize / (double) fftFrameSize;
        inFifoLatency = fftFrameSize - stepSize;
        if (gRover == 0)
            gRover = inFifoLatency;

        int c = 0;
        int round = 0;

        /* main processing loop */
        for (i = 0; i < numSampsToProcess; i++) {

            /* As long as we have not yet collected enough data just read in */
            gInFIFO[(int) gRover] = indata[(int) i];
            outdata[(int) i] = gOutFIFO[(int) (gRover - inFifoLatency)];
            gRover++;

            /* now we have enough data for processing */
            if (gRover >= fftFrameSize) {

                c++;
                if (c > 100) {
                    // Log.d("Liwei", "round= " + round++);
                    System.out.println("PitchShifter2.PitchShift(.....................): Liwei" + "round= " + round++);
                    c = 0;
                }

                gRover = inFifoLatency;

                /* do windowing and re,im interleave */
                for (k = 0; k < fftFrameSize; k++) {
                    window = -.5 * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (double) k / (double) fftFrameSize) + .5;
                    gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k)] = (float) (gInFIFO[(int) k] * window);
                    gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k + 1)] = 0.0F;
                }

                /* ***************** ANALYSIS ******************* */
                /* do transform */
                ShortTimeFourierTransform(gFFTworksp, fftFrameSize, -1);

                /* this is the analysis step */
                for (k = 0; k <= fftFrameSize2; k++) {

                    /* de-interlace FFT buffer */
                    real = gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k)];
                    imag = gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k + 1)];

                    /* compute magnitude and phase */
                    magn = 2.0 * Math.sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
                    phase = MathUtilities.atan2(imag, real);

                    /* compute phase difference */
                    tmp = phase - gLastPhase[(int) k];
                    gLastPhase[(int) k] = (float) phase;

                    /* subtract expected phase difference */
                    tmp -= (double) k * expct;

                    /* map delta phase into +/- Pi interval */
                    qpd = (long) (tmp / Math.PI);
                    if (qpd >= 0)
                        qpd += qpd & 1;
                    else
                        qpd -= qpd & 1;
                    tmp -= Math.PI * (double) qpd;

                    /* get deviation from bin frequency from the +/- Pi interval */
                    tmp = osamp * tmp / (2.0 * Math.PI);

                    /* compute the k-th partials' true frequency */
                    tmp = (double) k * freqPerBin + tmp * freqPerBin;

                    /* store magnitude and true frequency in analysis arrays */
                    gAnaMagn[(int) k] = (float) magn;
                    gAnaFreq[(int) k] = (float) tmp;

                }

                /* ***************** PROCESSING ******************* */
                /* this does the actual pitch shifting */
                for (int zero = 0; zero < fftFrameSize; zero++) {
                    gSynMagn[zero] = 0;
                    gSynFreq[zero] = 0;
                }

                for (k = 0; k <= fftFrameSize2; k++) {
                    index = (long) (k * pitchShift);
                    if (index <= fftFrameSize2) {
                        gSynMagn[(int) index] += gAnaMagn[(int) k];
                        gSynFreq[(int) index] = gAnaFreq[(int) k] * pitchShift;
                    }
                }

                /* ***************** SYNTHESIS ******************* */
                /* this is the synthesis step */
                for (k = 0; k <= fftFrameSize2; k++) {

                    /* get magnitude and true frequency from synthesis arrays */
                    magn = gSynMagn[(int) k];
                    tmp = gSynFreq[(int) k];

                    /* subtract bin mid frequency */
                    tmp -= (double) k * freqPerBin;

                    /* get bin deviation from freq deviation */
                    tmp /= freqPerBin;

                    /* take osamp into account */
                    tmp = 2.0 * Math.PI * tmp / osamp;

                    /* add the overlap phase advance back in */
                    tmp += (double) k * expct;

                    /* accumulate delta phase to get bin phase */
                    gSumPhase[(int) k] += (float) tmp;
                    phase = gSumPhase[(int) k];

                    /* get real and imag part and re-interleave */
                    gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k)] = (float) (magn * Math.cos(phase));
                    gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k + 1)] = (float) (magn * Math.sin(phase));
                }

                /* zero negative frequencies */
                for (k = fftFrameSize + 2; k < 2 * fftFrameSize; k++)
                    gFFTworksp[(int) k] = 0.0F;

                /* do inverse transform */
                ShortTimeFourierTransform(gFFTworksp, fftFrameSize, 1);

                /* do windowing and add to output accumulator */
                for (k = 0; k < fftFrameSize; k++) {
                    window = -.5 * Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * (double) k / (double) fftFrameSize) + .5;
                    gOutputAccum[(int) k] += (float) (2.0 * window * gFFTworksp[(int) (2 * k)] / (fftFrameSize2 * osamp));
                }
                for (k = 0; k < stepSize; k++)
                    gOutFIFO[(int) k] = gOutputAccum[(int) k];

                /* shift accumulator */
                // memmove(gOutputAccum, gOutputAccum + stepSize, fftFrameSize *
                // sizeof(float));
                for (k = 0; k < fftFrameSize; k++) {
                    gOutputAccum[(int) k] = gOutputAccum[(int) (k + stepSize)];
                }

                /* move input FIFO */
                for (k = 0; k < inFifoLatency; k++)
                    gInFIFO[(int) k] = gInFIFO[(int) (k + stepSize)];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ShortTimeFourierTransform(float[] fftBuffer, long fftFrameSize, long sign) {

        float wr, wi, arg, temp;
        float tr, ti, ur, ui;
        long i, bitm, j, le, le2, k;

        for (i = 2; i < 2 * fftFrameSize - 2; i += 2) {
            for (bitm = 2, j = 0; bitm < 2 * fftFrameSize; bitm <<= 1) {
                if ((i & bitm) != 0)
                    j++;
                j <<= 1;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                temp = fftBuffer[(int) i];
                fftBuffer[(int) i] = fftBuffer[(int) j];
                fftBuffer[(int) j] = temp;
                temp = fftBuffer[(int) (i + 1)];
                fftBuffer[(int) (i + 1)] = fftBuffer[(int) (j + 1)];
                fftBuffer[(int) (j + 1)] = temp;
                // temp = fftBuffer[i];
                // fftBuffer[i] = fftBuffer[j];
                // fftBuffer[j] = temp;
                // temp = fftBuffer[i + 1];
                // fftBuffer[i + 1] = fftBuffer[j + 1];
                // fftBuffer[j + 1] = temp;
            }

            long max = (long) (MathUtilities.log(fftFrameSize) / MathUtilities.log(2.0) + .5);
            for (k = 0, le = 2; k < max; k++) {
                le <<= 1;
                le2 = le >> 1;
                ur = 1.0F;
                ui = 0.0F;
                arg = (float) Math.PI / (le2 >> 1);
                wr = (float) Math.cos(arg);
                wi = (float) (sign * Math.sin(arg));
                for (j = 0; j < le2; j += 2) {

                    for (i = j; i < 2 * fftFrameSize; i += le) {
                        tr = fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2)] * ur - fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2 + 1)] * ui;
                        ti = fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2)] * ui + fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2 + 1)] * ur;
                        fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2)] = fftBuffer[(int) i] - tr;
                        fftBuffer[(int) (i + le2 + 1)] = fftBuffer[(int) (i + 1)] - ti;
                        fftBuffer[(int) i] += tr;
                        fftBuffer[(int) (i + 1)] += ti;
                        // tr = fftBuffer[i + le2] * ur - fftBuffer[i + le2 + 1]
                        // * ui;
                        // ti = fftBuffer[i + le2] * ui + fftBuffer[i + le2 + 1]
                        // * ur;
                        // fftBuffer[i + le2] = fftBuffer[i] - tr;
                        // fftBuffer[i + le2 + 1] = fftBuffer[i + 1] - ti;
                        // fftBuffer[i] += tr;
                        // fftBuffer[i + 1] += ti;

                    }
                    tr = ur * wr - ui * wi;
                    ui = ur * wi + ui * wr;
                    ur = tr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I get byte array from sound file, convert it into float array and pass to PitchShift2() and 
after that I convert that float array to byte array, form a stream from byte array and pass it to the player.
but it gives an exception "Unsupported file format".

I have also taken care of Endianness while converting bytes to floats and vise-versa.

can anyone tell me how to use this class properly.